# Apache Spark 2.3.1 compatibility with Hadoop 3.0 in HDP 3.0

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am plannig to upgrade from Hortonworks Data platform[HDP] (version 2.6.x) to HDP 3.0. But, there seems to be some major bugs in Apache Spark 2.3.x and its integration with Hadoop 3.0, which are still unresolved in Apache Spark JIRA issues. Although the Spark development team is working to resolve them. Do these issues have a workaround/resolutions by Hortonworks team, or do they still exist in HDP 3.0?

Some unresolved issues concerning my use case:

1. Spark DataFrames does not work with Hadoop 3.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18673
2. Kerberos Ticket renewal fails in Hadoop 3 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24493
3. Spark run on Hadoop 3 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23534

Comment: That might be a better quesiton for Hortonworks Support / Community forum

Comment: Common sense: stick to the Spark run-time that ships with HDP since it has gone through a battery of NRT ;  and read their release notes about known issues. And if you are too cheap to pay them for support, well, you'll have to try it out by yourself... That's the rule of that game.

Comment: Nothing is mentioned about the above mentioned issues in Known issues of HDP 3.0 release notes @SamsonScharfrichter

Comment: All 3 issues are "unassigned" which means that nobody really cares...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked integration with HDP Spark-2.3.1 and Hadoop - 3.0.1. It works perfectly and above issues were resolved in HDP version of Spark, but were not provided in HDP-3 release notes.
Check the community [answer](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/226780/apache-spark-231-does-not-work-with-hadoop-30.html)